# Inline assembly on x64 via a DLL

Tags: c++, c, assembly, dll, inline

Today I read on the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ks26t93.aspx) website, that inline assembly is not supported on ARM and x64 processors. Since I'm not good at C, C++ or ASM, I couldn't test it out myself, but it sparked my interest.

I wondered if it is not possible to do this in Visual Studio, since its on the MSDN website.

Regardless of the answer to my first question, my second question remains: is it possible to compile a DLL with inline ASM, which is then called via a x64 C/C++ program to execute the inline ASM. 
If so, why, and if not: why not.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wouldn't MSDN be the correct addressee for this question? We are not the Microsoft support forum.

Comment: I have not experience with the MSDN forums and I do here. Secondly I don't know if this 'issue' is related to MS or if it is not possible in general.

Comment: Inline-assmbly is not part of the C language. So, of course it is MS-specific. Wrt you not knowing the MSDN-forum: non sequitur. That's not an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As specified by the MSDN, the *VC++ compiler* doesn't support inline assembly on those platforms. Of course it's not an intrinsic limitation of those platforms - it's just a feature not implemented in those versions of VC++, other compilers (e.g. gcc) support it just fine. Nothing so strange, it's not a standard feature (as in: a feature required by the C or C++ standard), it's just a common extension.

Still, even with VC++ you don't need to go as far as making a dll - you can just assemble your asm file into an object module, and link it together with the other ones (generated e.g. by the C or C++ compiler) into a single executable. This is in fact the procedure they recommend to mix C/C++ and assembly - the Microsoft assembler itself is shipped along with VC++ as always.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: ...because `size_t` is `unsigned`... ? ;)

Comment: The assembler is distinct from the C/C++ compiler proper, but it ships with Visual Studio.

Comment: Inline assembly is a compiler extension, thus not standardised at all. Just because two compilers support it does not mean youj can use the same construct/syntax for it on both implementations.

Comment: @LPs: exactly =)

Comment: @Olaf: of course, but my point here was essentially to clear up the potential misunderstanding that it's an intrinsic problem of those platforms - which of course doesn't make sense, it's just that MS chose not to implement this common extension. I'll try to make this clearer.

Comment: As I wrote, it is a matter of the implementation. Sorry, I thought was was obvious, as the question cites from the VisualStudio text. How would that be relevant for gcc? (retorical question)